# C How do I simplify this For loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

So recently I started a course that is teaching C and my project was to create a user input based program that creates a pyramid with two spaces between each side of the tower. I have found a solution however I do not believe I am using this correctly, is there a way I could simplify this? 
The height choice should range from 1-8 and be made up of #

```
{
// User Check Point
int value;
do
{
// User Prompt for integer
    value = get_int("Height: ");
}
while (value > 8 ||value < 1);
// Once user value is sufficient code will continue    
{
// loop to create pyramid   

printf("\n       ");
for (int i = 7;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("  ");
for (int i = 7;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("\n      ");
for (int i = 6;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("  ");
for (int i = 6;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("\n     ");
for (int i = 5;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("  ");
for (int i = 5;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("\n    ");
for (int i = 4;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("  ");
for (int i = 4;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("\n   ");
for (int i = 3;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("  ");
for (int i = 3;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("\n  ");
for (int i = 2;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("  ");
for (int i = 2;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("\n ");
for (int i = 1;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("  ");
for (int i = 1;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("\n");
for (int i = 0;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("  ");
for (int i = 0;i<value;i++) putchar('#');
printf("\n");
}
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seems to be a nested `for` loop since there are no curly braces are provided and it'll simply accept a single most neighborhood statement.

Comment: The general idea with repetitive patterns is: Identify what  parts of the repetitive code stays the same and what part changes. Try to find a rule for the changes (here: start value rises with each other step). Implement a loop or formula with that rule. It's good that you feel uncomfortable with the code, and it's good that you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your question is bit ambiguous. Assuming you need to create a pyramid where size is given by user you can try with follows:

```
int i, j, value; 
for(i=1; i<=value; i++) { 
    for(j=i; j<value; j++) { 
        printf(" "); 
    }
    for(j=1; j<=(2*i-1); j++) { 
        printf("#"); 
    } 
    printf("\n"); 
}
```

This isn't the exact answer, but will be a good start.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Hope that's what you want:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < value; i++ ) {
       for(int j = 0; j < value - i - 1; j++) {
           printf(" ");
       }
       for(int j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
           printf("#");
       }
       printf(" ");

       for(int j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
           printf("#");
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
```

The result when `value = 7`:

```
      # #                                                                                                                                                   
     ## ##                                                                                                                                                  
    ### ###                                                                                                                                                 
   #### ####                                                                                                                                                
  ##### #####                                                                                                                                               
 ###### ######                                                                                                                                              
####### #######
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that is not what the teacher is looking for (but gives the right answer):

```
char pounds[]="########################";
for(int ii=1; ii<=value; ii++)
{
    printf("%8.*s  %.*s\n",ii,pounds,ii,pounds);
}
```

The * formatting in C does what you need but you also could have accomplished it by setting a string each cycle with the correct length.

I expect they are looking for nested loops.  Something like this is more what they want to see:

```
for(int ii=1;ii<=value;ii++) {
    for(int jj=0;jj<value; jj++) {
        if(jj<value-ii) {
            printf(" ");
        } else {
            printf("#");
        }
    }
    printf("  ");
    for(int jj=0;jj<ii; jj++) {
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```